# Spring MongoTemplate not a part of ongoing transaction

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions

I am attempting to transition to using MongoDB Transactions via Spring Data Mongo now that MongoDB 4.0 supports transactions, and Spring Data Mongo 2.1.5.Release supports it as well.

According to the Spring Data Mongo Documentation, you should be able to use the Spring MongoTransactionManager and have the MongoTemplate recognize and participate in ongoing transactions:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#_transactions_with_mongotransactionmanager

However, this following test fails:

```
@Autowired
private TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository;

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@BeforeTransaction
public void beforeTranscation() {
    cleanAndInitDatabase();
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void transactionViaAnnotation() {
    TestEntityA entity1 = new TestEntityA();
    entity1.setValueA("a");

    TestEntityA entity2 = new TestEntityA();
    entity2.setValueA("b");

    testEntityRepository.save(entity1);
    testEntityRepository.save(entity2);

    // throw new RuntimeException("prevent commit");

    List<TestEntityA> entities = testEntityRepository.findAll(Example.of(entity1));
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, entities.size());  // SUCCEEDS

    entities = testEntityRepository.findAll(Example.of(entity2));
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, entities.size());  // SUCCEEDS

    entities = mongoTemplate.findAll(TestEntityA.class);
    Assertions.assertEquals(2, entities.size());  // FAILS - expected: <2> but was: <0>
}
```

It appears that the testEntityRepository works fine with the transaction.  The asserts succeed, and if I uncomment the exception line, neither of the records are persisted to the database.

However, trying to use the mongoTemplate directly to do a query doesn't work as it appears to not participate in the transaction.

The documentation I have linked shows using the **template** directly within a **@Transactional** method like I am attempting.  However, the text says

> *MongoTemplate* can also participate in other, ongoing transactions.

which could be interpreted to mean the template can be used with different transactions, and not necessarily the *implicit* transaction.  But that is not what the example would indicate.

Any ideas what is happening or how to get the template to participate in the same *implicit* transaction?

Comment: From the snippet above it's a bit hard to tell what's the issue. To participate in an ongoing (non MongoDB native) transaction managed by eg. a `HibernateTransactionManager` you need enable `SessionSynchronisation` for `MongoTemplate` via `template.setSessionSynchronization(ALWAYS)`.
Please verify state within an `@AfterTransaction` block and use `@Rollback` for your tests. Maybe you can share a full sample with the failing test (a gist maybe?) so that we can run it and see what actually happens.

Comment: I have tried setting session synchronization to both possible values, but I get the same results.  I'm working on a production system, so my environment isn't simple, so I am working on seeing if I can pull out enough details.